# Strongly balanced graphs construction - didn't understand part of the construction

Tags: graph-theory

From here: https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/StronglyBalanced.pdf
"
Throughout this section set n = u - 1 and express e = kn + r where k and
r are integers and 0 <= r < n. Note that n >= 2k - 1 and n >= 2k if r > 0.
Denote by C(n,k) a graph with vertex set {1,2, . . . ,n} and edge set {{x, y}:
|x - y| <= k - 1, modulo n},k >= 2. Denote by D(n,k) the graph obtained
from C(n,k) by joining a new vertex n + 1 to all vertices of C(n, k). Let
R(n, r) be the following set of points almost equidistributed around C(n, k):
R(n,r) = {x:|(x - 1)r/n| < |xr/n|, 1 <= x <= n,x an integer}
**Note that |R(n, r)| = r**, and for any n’ consecutive modulo n integers, less than
n’r/n + 1 of them belong to R(n, r).
"
I don't understand why |R(n, r)| = r. I see any x satisfy the inequality so I guess "almost equidistributed around C(n, k)" is what I don't understand. What "almost equidistributed" means?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So nobody gonna answer me until I use MathJax?

Comment: I should I know why others will not answer? I will not answer because I know nothing about graph theory.

Comment: Ok lol qwertyuiop

Comment: I think the vertical bars in the definition of R(n,r) are (unfortunately) referring to a floor (or ceiling function). Check out this desmos thing https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iu3ukah4t6  Every time the two dots are in different places, it corresponds to an x in the set

Comment: I think you are right buddy. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!